# 2 balls distributed between 2 urns. (~ Bose-Einstein vs Maxwell-Boltzmann ?)

Tags: probability, proof-verification, elementary-probability

Consider the following two problems:

1. Two *different* balls are randomly distributed between two different urns. What is the probability of both balls being in the same urn?
2. Two *indistinguishable* balls are randomly distributed between two different urns. What is the probability of both balls being in the same urn?

Both problems seem to have simple solutions:

1. There are 4 elementary events: { ab | }, { a | b }, { b | a }, { | ab }. Two of them satisfy the composite event. All the elementary events have equal probabilities, thus we get an answer: 2/4 or 1/2.
2. There are 3 elementary events: { ** | }, { * | * }, { | ** }. With the same reasoning here we get the probability of both balls being in the same urn equal 2/3.

To me it seems unnatural that in these two problems we get different answers. I do not see any practical reason why the type of balls would change probability we assign to both of them getting into the same urn.

After all, if, for example, their difference was in color, we could check their position blindfolded and still get results. So it should not matter to us if they are colored or not in the first place.

There is a clear correspondence between the two solutions:

- { ** | } ~ { ab | }
- { * | * } ~ { a | b }, { b | a }
- { | ** } ~ { | ab }

Then perhaps the events we considered elementary for the second solution are not such? The second event being composite and the answer still being 1/2?

It seems to me that this question boils down to the following: how to choose a sample space for a problem and how to determine whether or not its events have equal probabilities. Is that a matter of experience and intuition?

(Now, just in case the two problems turn out to indeed have different answers, I would like to ask another question. What if we are explicitly given that the balls might be distinguishable or not distinguishable with equal probabilities. What would be the answer then? 1/2, 2/3 or something in between?)

P.S. I have tried googling for my question but didn't have much luck. It still seems unlikely that I'm the first person to ask something along these lines, but I honestly just couldn't find anything. In addition to that, I'd like to say that I only just started my probability course and do not know much about the notion of probability distribution. This problem seems simple enough to be solved without using advanced theory though. Thanks.

Comment: In case 1 there are $4$ **equiprobable** outcomes and in $2$ of them the balls end up in the same urn. That gives probability $\frac24=\frac12$. In case 2 there are $3$ outcomes, but these are **not equiprobable**. The outcomes $\{**|\}$ and $\{|**\}$ have probability $\frac14$ again and the outcome $\{*|*\}$ has probability $\frac12$. So again probability $\frac12$ that the balls end up in the same urn. So your intuition is okay.

Comment: @drhab I did consider that possibility in one paragraph. What I do not understand in this case is why exactly does the outcome $\{ * | * \}$ have a probability that's different from the other two.

Comment: Let's say that we place the two indistinghuisable balls one by one. If the first ball has been placed then there are two possibilities for the second ball: it wil be placed in the same urn as the first or in the other urn. Both outcomes have the same probability. So the probability that it will end up in the same urn as the first is $\frac12$ and also the probability that it will end up in a different urn (case $\{*|*\}$) is $\frac12$.

Comment: @drhab That does not seem to solve the problem. Placing the balls in one by one makes them distinguishable. I would like to consider them as completely theoretically indistinguishable. So it's better to imagine that they somehow were already in their urns at the beginning of time.

Comment: @IliaZaichuk when you wrote $\{ * | * \} \sim \{ a | b \}, \{ b | a \}$ you seem very close to understanding, you are right that in case $2$ that there three possible configurations, but your own correspondance shows that these three configurations are not equally likely as drhab has pointed out

Comment: No. Placing the balls one by one does not make them distinguishable. There is no essential difference between throwing two balls at the same time or throwing them one by one. The question of being distinghuishable (or not) only turns up it we look (at the end of the experiment) at the outcomes. We see $2$ distinguishable balls (and count $4$ possible outcomes) or $2$ indistinguishable balls (and count $3$ possible outcomes). Also you can - if you wish - choose blindfolded the first ball to be placed and the second ball to be placed.

Comment: @drhab Indeed that does not make the balls themselves distinguishable. It is just that by putting them in one by one we enumerate them, thus enabling ourselves to operate with them as if they were distinguishable and count the outcomes accordingly. The thing is, I do not see a way to describe the two different states inside $\{ * | * \}$  without somehow telling the balls apart - one way or another. And if the problem states that the balls are indistinguishable, I do not see the reason why we need to tell them apart.

Comment: The two different states inside $\{*|*\}$ can allready be described on base of the fact that we deal with number $2$ here. We don't even need balls for that. If there are $n$ indistinghuishable objects then there are $n!$ ways to put them in a row. If the balls are indistinguishable then there is no reason to tell them apart, but (as you found out yourself on base of your intuition) there is a reason to tell the ways to put them in a row apart.

Comment: @drhab Huh, I think I see your point. $n$ indistinguishable objects still do have $n!$ permutations, even if though the permutations are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question concerns the issue of how to assign prior probabilities and lies at the foundation of probability theory. Most books on probability theory simply assume a particular assignment of probability measure over the sample space (precisely $\sigma$-algebra of events). However the exercise of assigning prior probabilities lies outside the domain of probability theory and extraneous principles have to be brought in. For example the so-called [principle of indifference](http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/ijsp/article/viewFile/59617/32596) says that if all outcomes are symmetric w.r.t. information available to you then all of them have to be assigned equal probability by virtue of this symmetry. This principle cannot be justified or derived within probability theory. There are other principles too, such as [maximum entropy principle](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/entropypost.pdf) and [transformation invariance](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/groups.pdf). Also see *Probability Theory: Logic of Science* by E.T. Jaynes.

So to answer your question specifically, depending on which list of outcomes you choose, applying the principle of indifference to that list assigns equal probabilities to  the outcomes in that list. Since this is a physical problem, experiments become the arbiter of which of them is correct.

Comment: "Assigning prior probabilities" does seem to describe my question quite well. As I understand it from your answer, probability theory does not deal with prior probabilities similarly to how, say, formal calculus doesn't quite "care" about being applied in physics? (can't find a way to word that well in English)

Comment: @IliaZaichuk To take up your calculus analogy, calculus tells you what you can do with functions once they are given. Calculus doesn't tell you which function you should be analyzing. That forms the input to calculus and therefore lies outside its domain. Similarly the list of prior probabilities is an input to probability theory.